# Scrollbar is cut off on side-nav

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am working on a little side project of a doc viewer, it has a side pane that allows the user to click to navigate to certain parts of a large document.

My whole goal with it is to get better with css3 and jQuery but I've run into a weird issue.

The side menu has a list of 10 and each one of those 10 onclick expand a subtree of 3 for a total of 30.

I have the following css for the side-nav and a jquery button that on click either shows or hides the nav.

```
.slide-out-bar {
    background-color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 210px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 146px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

My, expectation is that the when the list grows past the screen the user will be able to scroll through the full list to see what they need.

Currently the scrollbar is just flat out cut off at the bottom and only scrolls partways. And I am not sure what's causing it or how to fix it.

I've tried debugging and googling results over the past day and I'm not getting anywhere. Can anyone give some advice?

Here is the full code on codepen
https://codepen.io/latimeks/pen/wrMWZg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

height: 100vh; means that the element should have the height 100% of the viewport (the whole browser window), not the container element, so you can't use it here, as you have the header above. You may want to arrange the elements with flex box or absolute positioning.

Comment: I see. I've never used flexbox before so now would be a good time to learn it. I'll come back and accept your answer if that fixes my problem

Comment: I'm a newbie too and need to look at things again and again. This site helps me all the time:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: After doing some dabbling and testing I actually got this to work. Your answer put me on the right track. Thank you